# ksqlDB: How to explicitly identify the Row Key when using CTAS

Tags: key, primary-key, ksqldb

I've spun up ksqlDB 0.9.0.

If this is a duplicate, and I really hope it is, my stack overflow search fu simply didn't catch it.

From a high level, I have a kafka stream input and two batch inputs (which must be merged) that I'm pushing daily.  I'm investigating ksqlDB as a way to merge the data and present a realtime view of that kafka stream with annotated data.

The general pattern I'm following is to first build a stream, then materialize a view so that I can join.  The "foo" version for a single batched table is something like:

```sql
-- Simple stream
CREATE STREAM events (
  -- rowkey here is technically both my key and my timestamp...but I can't seem to control timestamp either... 
  -- "KSQL currently only supports KEY columns named ROWKEY."  << REALLY??
  rowkey BIGINT KEY
  , event_id VARCHAR
  , source_id VARCHAR
  , another_id VARCHAR
  )
  WITH(kafka_topic='events', value_format='json', partitions=256)
  ;

-- Foo Stream (batched data #1)
CREATE STREAM foo_stream (
  -- rowkey here is actually "source_id"
  rowkey VARCHAR KEY
  , metadata_id VARCHAR 
  )
  WITH(kafka_topic='foo', value_format='json', partitions=256)
  ;

-- Materialized view of Foo
CREATE TABLE foo AS SELECT
  -- suddenly, we have TWO rowkeys here: source_id (the real one) and rowkey (the implicit one).. and no way to correct
  f.rowkey as source_id
  , LATEST_BY_OFFSET(f.metadata_id) as metadata_id
  FROM foo_stream f
  GROUP BY f.rowkey
  EMIT CHANGES
  ;

-- why oh why for the love of all things sql
-- Name                 : FOO
--  Field       | Type
----------------------------------------------
--  ROWKEY      | VARCHAR(STRING)  (primary key)
--  SOURCE_ID   | VARCHAR(STRING)                 <-- why can't this be primary?
--  METADATA_ID | VARCHAR(STRING)
----------------------------------------------

-- Simple stream of Bar (batched data #2)
CREATE STREAM bar_stream (
  -- not to be overloaded with rowkeys... but this one is actually `metadata_id`
  rowkey VARCHAR KEY
  , desc VARCHAR 
  , title VARCHAR 
  )
  WITH(kafka_topic='bar', value_format='json', partitions=256)
  ;

-- Materialized view of Bar
CREATE TABLE bar AS SELECT
  -- this would be comical, but it's not.
  b.rowkey as metadata_id
  , LATEST_BY_OFFSET(b.desc) as desc
  , LATEST_BY_OFFSET(b.title) as title
  FROM bar_stream b
  GROUP BY b.rowkey    -- I truly dream in rowkeys
  EMIT CHANGES
  ;

-- Name                 : BAR
--  Field       | Type
----------------------------------------------
--  ROWKEY      | VARCHAR(STRING)  (primary key)
--  METADATA_ID | VARCHAR(STRING)
--  DESC        | VARCHAR(STRING)
--  TITLE       | VARCHAR(STRING)
----------------------------------------------
```

My final goal is to have something like this (except this really doesn't work, because rowkeys):

```sql
-- make sure that the criteria uses the TABLE's key column ROWKEY instead of METADATA_ID
-- more rowkey madness
CREATE STREAM composed AS SELECT
  e.another_id
  , b.metadata_id as metadata_id
  , b.desc as desc
  , b.title as title
  FROM events e
  JOIN foo f ON f.source_id = e.source_id
  JOIN bar b ON b.metadata_id = f.metadata_id
  ;
```

And then be able to do a simple Pull query:

```sql
-- and this week's rowkey comes in at number 5
SELECT * FROM composed WHERE rowkey='a perfectly good another id';
```

I really don't know how to control Keys in streams and PRIMARY KEYs in the materialized views.  Please help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use ksqlDB 0.10 (which was literally announced a day later from the question).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem was related to the fact that the keys are inferred from `GROUP BY`, so what goes into `GROUP BY` goes into the key. Can be one value, but can be a concatenated list of values as well.